# Unable to use Kotlin-android-extension along with Kotlin/native

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-native

I want to build a multi-platform `Kotlin` module that works with both `ios` and android. But when I use

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-android'
```

I am no longer able to resolve kotlinx in my imports.

This is my android **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.phonepe.mykotlinnativesample"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

def butterknife_version = '8.8.1'

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknife_version"
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
expectedBy project(":common")
}
```

this is my common **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'konan'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-common'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
}
konan.targets = ['iphone', 'iphone_sim']
def frameworkName = 'KotlinHello'
konanArtifacts {
framework(frameworkName)
}
task lipo(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'build') {
def frameworks = files(
            "$buildDir/konan/bin/iphone/${frameworkName}.framework/$frameworkName",
        "$buildDir/konan/bin/iphone_sim/${frameworkName}.framework/$frameworkName"
)
def output = file("$buildDir/konan/bin/iphone_universal/${frameworkName}.framework/$frameworkName")
inputs.files frameworks
outputs.file output
executable = 'lipo'
args = frameworks.files
args += ['-create', '-output', output]
}
task copyFramework(type: Copy, dependsOn: lipo) {
from("$buildDir/konan/bin/iphone") {
    include '*/Headers/*'
    include '*/Modules/*'
    include '*/Info.plist'
}
from "$buildDir/konan/bin/iphone_universal"
into "${rootProject.rootDir}/ios"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin/Native currently does not support kapt or any other kotlinx libraries. We can use kapt, in android platform of the app, but not in the main common module itself.